# How to solve LNK2019 and LNK 1120 from this code?

Tags: c++, lnk2019

When I try to compile this code, Visual Studio 2022 shows these problems.

```
> `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cashregister::acceptamount(int)" (?acceptamount@cashregister@@QEAAXH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl sellproduct(class dispensertype &,class cashregister &)" (?sellproduct@@YAXAEAVdispensertype@@AEAVcashregister@@@Z)   Fruit Juice Machine C:\Users\1\source\repos\Fruit Juice Machine\Fruit Juice Machine\Fruit Juice Machine.obj 1`
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cashregister::cashregister(void)" (??0cashregister@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main    Fruit Juice Machine C:\Users\1\source\repos\Fruit Juice Machine\Fruit Juice Machine\Fruit Juice Machine.obj 1
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl dispensertype::dispensertype(int,int)" (??0dispensertype@@QEAA@HH@Z) referenced in function main    Fruit Juice Machine C:\Users\1\source\repos\Fruit Juice Machine\Fruit Juice Machine\Fruit Juice Machine.obj 1
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 3 unresolved externals  Fruit Juice Machine C:\Users\1\source\repos\Fruit Juice Machine\x64\Debug\Fruit Juice Machine.exe   1
```

These are the code: (The source code is from DATA STRUCTURES USING C++ SECOND EDITION Chapter 1)

FROM Fruit Juice Machine.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cashregister.h"
#include "dispensertype.h"
```

void showselection() {

```
cout << "**********HEALTHY'S FRUIT JUICE MACHINE" << endl;
cout << "To select an item, please enter" << endl;
cout << "1.Apple Juice " << endl;
cout << "2.Grape Juice " << endl;
cout << "3.Mango Juice " << endl;
cout << "9. exit" << endl;
```

}

void sellproduct(dispensertype & product, cashregister & pcounter) {

```
int amount;
int amount1;

if (product.getnumberoftimes() > 0) {
    cout << "Please deposit " << product.getcost() << " cents" << endl;
    cin >> amount;
    if (amount < product.getcost()) {
        cout << "The amount is not enough,please deposit more" << product.getcost() - amount << " cents" << endl;
        cin >> amount1;
        amount = amount + amount1;
    }

    else {
        pcounter.acceptamount(amount);
        product.makesale();
        cout << "Please collect your item and enjoy!" << endl;
    }
}
else {
    cout << "Sorry, the item is sold out" << endl;
}
cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
```

}

int main() {

```
cashregister counter;
dispensertype applejuice(1,2);
dispensertype grapejuice(3,4);
dispensertype orangejuice(5,6);

int choice;

showselection();
cin >> choice;
while (choice != 9) {

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        sellproduct(applejuice, counter);
        break;

    case 2:
        sellproduct(grapejuice, counter);
        break;

    case 3:
        sellproduct(orangejuice, counter);
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;
    }
    showselection();
    cin >> choice;
}

return 0;
```

}

FROM dispensertype.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class dispensertype {

    int numberoftime;
    int cost;

public:
    int getnumberoftimes()const {
        return numberoftime;
    }

    int getcost()const {
        return cost;
    }

    void makesale() {
        numberoftime--;
    }

    dispensertype();

    dispensertype(int setnumberoftime, int setcost);

    
};
```

FROM dispensertype.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dispensertype.h"


int dispensertype::getcost() const{
    return cost;

}

int dispensertype::getnumberoftimes()const {
    return numberoftimes;
}

void dispensertype::makesale() {
    numberoftimes--;
}

dispensertype::dispensertype() {
    numberoftime = 100;
    cost = 5;

}
 
dispensertype::dispensertype(int setnumberoftime, int setcost) {

    if (setnumberoftime >= 0) {
        numberoftime = setnumberoftime;
    }
    else {
        numberoftime = 100;
    }

    if (setcost >= 0) {
        cost = setcost;
    }
    else {
        cost = 5;
    }
}
```

FROM cashregister.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class cashregister {

    int cashonhand;

public:
    int getcurrentbalance()const;

    void acceptamount(int amountin);

    cashregister();

    cashregister(int cashin);

};
```

FROM cashregister.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "cashregister.h"

int cashregister::getcurrentbalance()const {

    return cashonhand;
}

void cashregister::acceptamount(int amountin) {
    cashonhand = cashonhand + amountin;

}

cashregister::cashregister() {
    cashonhand = 500;
}

cashregister::cashregister(int cashin){

    if (cashin>=0) {
        cashonhand = cashin;
    }
    else {
        cashonhand = 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `cashregister.cpp` part of your project? It should be listed in "Solution Explorer"

Comment: I try to add cashregister.cpp and dispensertype.cpp to the source files in the solution explorer, and it works. Thanks a lot!